# Sequence of tenses for facts irrelevant of the moment of speech

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense, backshifting, reported-speech

Let's consider two sentences:

> (1) I suggested that the word zeitgeist **was** of German origin.
>   (2) The lecturer said the Pluto's orbital period **is** more than 200 years.

In both cases, the facts are always valid and  irrelevant of the moment of speech and context. I've heard sequence of tenses is not required in such cases. Are past and present tenses interchangeable in both of them? **Would it be correct to say**:

> (1) I suggested that the word zeitgeist **is** of German origin.
>   (2) The lecturer said the Pluto's orbital period **was** more than 200 years.

Comment: Your last two sentences and the first ones are different. Simply, the past time means something may be no longer valid! ***"Pluto's orbital period was more than 200 years."*** conveys ambiguity on the current status.

Comment: The past tense is *silent* with respect to whether the past assertion is now true.  There is no implication that it is or may be no longer valid. "I suggested that the word *zeitgeist* was of German origin" is simply a statement of what was suggested, without reference to the present.  You do not have to change **was** to **is** if your intention is to *recount* or *relate* what you had suggested. If, however, you wish to *reassert* your position, then you can change **was** to **is**, and change the past tense to present perfect: *I've suggested that the word 'zeitgeist' is of German origin.*

Answer (score 3):

There is no grammatical requirement, when reporting what was said in the past, to use the present tense if the *assertion* is true in the present.

> The professor said Pluto **took** more than 200 Earth-years to orbit the
>   sun.

All that sentence does is *report* what the professor said, without reference to the truth of the assertion; it is perfectly valid regardless of the truth or falsehood of the assertion about Pluto.

If your intention is purely to *report* what was said, it is best to use the past tense:

> I **said** the word 'zeitgeist' **was** of German origin.
>
> The professor said Pluto **took** more than 200 Earth-years to orbit the
>   sun.

That said, speakers are often doing more than one thing simultaneously, especially when speaking in an impromptu manner, and a native speaker could easily make those statements using the present tense:

> I **said** that the word 'zeitgeist' **is** of German origin.

and want you to understand two things thereby:

1) he said 'zeitgeist' was of German origin on a past occasion
2) he would say it again because his opinion is unchanged

> The professor said Pluto **takes** more than 200 Earth-years to orbit the
>   sun.

1) the professor made that claim
2) the speaker believes the professor and is passing the fact on to the listener

P.S. The native speaker wouldn't be consciously debating whether to use present tense or past tense.